# Intersection Type Data

Tags: data, intersection, streets

Would anyone have any input as to where I could find a table/shapefile/feature class that describes the intersection type of roads? I've looked into TIGER roads, StreetMap premium, OpenStreetMap tables. Specifically looking for "street-light", "4 way stop", etc.

If such a database even exists.

Comment: radouxju has already given a specific answer, but I was going to mention that the only place I've ever seen this kind of data was a the local municipal level (city/county), particularly their transportation or streets maintenance departments, or as part of proprietary datasets used for traffic navigation. More limited forms from crowd-sourced data - I know someone with a Garmin streets gps that pulls location data of red-light cameras from somewhere and integrates them as points with vicinity warnings.

Answer (score 2):

[Navteq-here](http://www.adci.com/navteq-here/gis/) does, but it is quite expensive. You can download a sample on their site to make sure it is what you want. I think [TeleAtlas](http://www.tele-mart.com/routing-logistics.php) also does.